# Pipe output of two separate ForEach-Object commands to the same file

Tags: powershell

I have the two below lines of Powershell code:

`gci -Path 'C:\<somefolder>\bin\' | ForEach-Object {$_.VersionInfo} > 'C:\temp\bin_contents.txt'`

`gci -Recurse 'C:\<somefolder>\bin\' | ForEach-Object { Get-Item $_.FullName -Stream * } | Where-Object stream -ne ':$Data'`

The first outputs the file name, file version, and product version of all files in the given folder to a text file.  The second outputs (for now, to the console) the alternate data stream of any files in the given folder.

My end goal, hopefully, is to pipe all of this to one file.  Ideally, figuring out the correct method to basically add an additional section/column to the text file that includes the ADS, if one exists, for any particular file in that location.  However, I cannot figure out how to combine these two lines, without breaking how each works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`about_Redirection` help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.4#powershell-redirection-operators):

> | Operator | Description | Syntax |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | > | Send specified stream to a file. | n> |
> | >> | Append specified stream to a file. | n>> |
> | >&1 | Redirects the specified stream to the Success stream. | n>&1 |

So to *append* to an existing file, use `>>`:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse 'C:\<somefolder>\bin\' | ForEach-Object { 
  Get-Item $_.FullName -Stream *
} | Where-Object stream -ne ':$Data' >> C:\temp\bin_contents.txt
```

---

Another option is to embed both statements in a separate script block and then write the output from that to a single file:

```
& {
  Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\<somefolder>\bin\' | ForEach-Object VersionInfo

  Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\<somefolder>\bin\' -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    Get-Item $_.FullName -Stream *
  } | Where-Object stream -ne ':$Data'
} > C:\temp\bin_contents.txt
```